# Google Sheets Unmatch and Split results

Tags: google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How to combine these two formulas:

Formula 1:

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT("RangedName1");ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("RangedName1");FILTER(SORT(UNIQUE(flatten(C3:H14));1;1); SORT(UNIQUE(flatten(C3:H14));1;1)<>"");0)))
```

This first formula, grabs all values from the input range C3:H14 (Columns A to F in this example) to filter duplicates and then the results are flattened and sorted into a single column, this flattened range is then substracted from RangeNamed1 and so the result is a range in a single column of values that do not appear in the range C3:H14.

```
 Confrontation range         RangedName1    Result
   A       B    .    F            G           H
------------------------------------------------------
Mango   Banana ... Apple      X Apple      Grapes
Banana  Carrot ... Orange     X Banana     Peach
                              X Carrot     .
                              X Orange     .
                                Peach      Watermelon
                              X Mango
                                Grapes
                                .
                                .
                                Watermelon
```

Formula 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(H3:H15)/4);4;ROW(H3:H15)));{ROW(H3:H15)\H3:H15};2;0)))
```

This second formula splits the result from Formula 1 (In this example column H) into multiple columns every 4 rows.

And so

```
                         Split Range
    H           I       J    .    .      M  
-------------------------------------------------
Grapes       Grapes     .             .
Peach        Peach      .             .
.            .          .             .
.            .          .             Watermelon
.
.
.          
Watermelon
```

When I try to use the Formula 1 into the Formula 2 (Replacing H3:H15) to combine them into a single formula it gives a **Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 1.** error.

How to combine them into a single formula?

Need to be sorted in ascending order only before it is split.

Comment: If you share an (editable) sample sheet, with some manually entered "desired results" I can show you how to do it formulaically.

Comment: Added a demo sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(
 {(ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(
 FILTER(M2:M; NOT(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(C2:H15); M2:M)))); 1; 0; 1)/A19))+1\QUERY(
 FILTER(M2:M; NOT(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(C2:H15); M2:M))); "where Col1 is not null")}; 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"); "offset 1"; 0);; 9^9))); " ")))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

I made a new tab called MK.Help and put this formula in cell A19:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP("X";{"X";QUERY({M2:M\ISNA(MATCH(M2:M;FLATTEN(C2:H15);0))};"select Col1 where Col2=TRUE and Col1<>'' order by Col1")};TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(SUM(ISNA(MATCH(M2:M;FLATTEN(C2:H15);0))*ISTEXT(M2:M))/4);4;2));0)))
```

It uses a trick of "looking up" the letter X into a constructed range consisting of the letter X placed on top of the query showing the correct names.  The [index] of that HLOOKUP is a SEQUENCE() array that is defined by the number 4, which you should see twice in the formula.  Change the 4 to change the shape of the results.

Answer (score 2):

to distribute J column into yellow cells in set of 4 per column you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(
 {(ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(
 FILTER(INDIRECT("NamedRange1"); ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("NamedRange1");
 FILTER(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(C2:H15)); 1; 1); 
 SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(C2:H15)); 1; 1)<>""); 0)))); 1; 0; 1)/N1))+1\
 FILTER(INDIRECT("NamedRange1"); ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("NamedRange1");
 FILTER(SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(C2:H15)); 1; 1); 
 SORT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(C2:H15)); 1; 1)<>""); 0)))}; 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"); "offset 1"; 0);; 9^9))); " ")))
```

note that N1 is a variable of sets. can be changed easily to whatever grid distribution you want or directly hardcoded to 4 if you wish

[image]